# Rotation of an array of vectors by an array of rotation matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

If we have a `3 x 3` rotation matrix `R`, it can be multiplied with `v`, a `3 x N` array - an array of `N` column vectors - to produce a new `3 x N` array of rotated vectors, like this:

```
v_rotated = R.dot(v)
```

Now suppose we have a `N x M x 3` array, `N` times `M` vectors, which I want to rotate with `N` different `3 x 3` rotation matrices (one rotation matrix for each "row" of vectors). This is straightforward to do with a loop, but is there a faster and more compact (vectorized) way to do it, e.g. with `numpy`'s `dot` or `tensorproduct`?

Example code for loop implementation:

```
from numpy import cos, sin, array, pi, linspace, random

# 100 different rotation matrices:
R = [array([[1, 0, 0], [0, cos(theta), -sin(theta)], [0, sin(theta), cos(theta)]]) for theta in linspace(0, pi, 100)]
# 100 x 200 random vectors:
v = random.random((100, 200, 3))

# rotate vectors in loop:
rotated_v = array([R_.dot(v_.T).T for R_, v_ in zip(R, v)])
```

Comment: Share the loopy code if you have implemented, so that we could check back on any proposed solution?

Comment: @Divakar added loopy code (toy example of course)

Comment: Maybe this question about how to calculate the rotation matrix vectorizing can be of use to someone: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67874876/12131616

Answer (score 7, accepted):

let's assume that `v.shape` is `(N, M, 3)` and `R.shape` is `(N, 3, 3)`, 
you can use `np.einsum`

```
import numpy as np
rotated_v = np.einsum('lij, lkj->lki', R, v)
```

where `l` is the index on `N`, `i` and `j` are the indexes on `3x3` rotation dimension, and `k` is the index on `M`.

I matched my result with your as follow:

```
>>> print np.allclose(my_rotated_v, your_rotated_v)
True
```