# How to vectorize the creation of N rotation matrix from a vector of angles?

Tags: python, performance, multidimensional-array, vectorization

**Data:**
*theta* is a vector of N angles.

**Question:** How to create a vector of N 2D rotation matrix from *theta* while vectorizing?

Without vectorizing I can think of a for loop:

```py
import numpy as np

N = 100
theta = np.random.rand(N)*2*np.pi

def R(theta_v):
    Rotation = np.empty((len(theta_v), 2, 2))
    for k, theta in enumerate(theta_v):
        Rotation[k] = np.array([ [np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)] ])
    return Rotation

Rotation = R(theta)
```

Is there a way to avoid the `for loop` in order to achieve a more efficient code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize your function by using the vectorized versions of cos and sin, then rearranging the result:

```py
def R_vec(theta):
    c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
    return np.array([c, -s, s, c]).T.reshape(len(theta),2,2)
```

For N=100, the vectorized versions is about 110 times faster than the original on my computer.

Comment: If theta is a n-dimensional array, the generalization of this answer is: `return np.array([[c, -s], [s, c]]).transpose((*range(2, 2+theta.ndim), 0 , 1))`.